# Algorithm to search regex pattern stuck for some txt

Tags: python, file-io

I created Unit Tests for algorithm to search regex pattern in txt files. It is stuck for some files during analysis of this regex:

```
(nr|numer|[fj]ak[^\r\n]{1,3}ura)\s((?!kas|par|rej|kl\.|kont|te[lł]|klien|zlece|trans|zam|dz|pkwiu|wydr))?(?!rachunk|lic)(.*\n){5}`
```

Test:

```
def testNIPMass(self):
    #mypath="E:\\Skrypt\\txts\\1"
    mypath="C:\\Users\\lataman\\Documents\\OCR\\PyVer\\skrypt\\txts\\1"
    container=schemeContainer.createObject("PL")
    for f in listdir(mypath):
        file = join(mypath,f)
        if isfile(file):
            tArray=utilities.fopen(file).split('\n')
            NIPclient=container.seekPattern("InvoiceNumber", tArray, returnPatterns=True)
            print("File: "+f+"\nInvoiceNumber: "+str(NIPclient))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `ł` in regex. You must changing coding for Unicode or remove it.
If that will not work, check this "stuck" files if they contain some strange characters.